# Pyspark simultaneously remove from 2 lists in dataframe

Tags: python, list, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm having a problem with huge data set and I'm looking for removing same indexed item from 2 lists.

Let me describe an example.

Imagine a Google search - list of 12 URLs from the page. First is an advertisement and the last one too, second and 7th is a picture link. Now I want *only* the organic `link`s.

Types can be randomly positioned in the list. I was checking the `array_remove` which is pretty nice but it can only remove specific item from 1 list and I'm not advanced enough to  figure out how to do it simultaneously for 2 lists. Sadly dataset is really big and I'm afraid that `posexplode` in not an option for me here.

Keep in mind it's a column of *lists*, not a column of individual items.

I'm looking for something like

```
if "adlink" or "picture" in typelist:
   remove it from typelist and remove same indexed item from urls list
```

```
  urls  |  type 
-----------------
[url1,  | [adlink, 
 url2,  |  picture,
 url3,  |  link,
 url4,  |  link,
 url5,  |  link, 
 url6,  |  link,
 url7,  |  picture,
 url8,  |  link,
 url9,  |  link,
 url10, |  link,
 url11, |  link,
 url12] |  adlink]
```

Desired output:

```
  urls  |  type 
-----------------
[url3,  | [link,
 url4,  |  link,
 url5,  |  link, 
 url6,  |  link,
 url8,  |  link,
 url9,  |  link,
 url10, |  link,
 url11] |  link]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.show()#your dataframe
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|urls                                                                       |type                                                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[url1, url2, url3, url4, url5, url6, url7, url8, url9, url10, url11, url12]|[adlink, picture, link, link, link, link, picture, link, link, link, link, adlink]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can use **`higher order functions`** as you have **`spark2.4`**(I could tell because u used **`array_remove`**). First, you can **zip** the arrays together using **`arrays_zip`**, and then use **`filter`** on the **`zipped array(type_urls)`** to *filter out* where ever **`type is 'adlink' and 'picture'`**, then select your desired columns from the zipped column using **`columname.arrayname`**.

**`Filter`**(higher order function), *basically allows you to apply filter to higher ordered data, without having to explode it(as you mentioned **posexplode**)*.
[Higher order functions](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/data-transformation/higher-order-lambda-functions.html)

**`arrays_zip`** *Returns a merged array of structs in which the N-th struct contains all N-th values of input arrays.*
[arrays_zip Pyspark API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip)

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("type_urls", F.arrays_zip(F.col("urls"),F.col("type"))).select("type_urls")\
  .withColumn("urls1", F.expr("""filter(type_urls, x-> x.type!='adlink' and x.type!='picture')"""))\
  .select(F.col("urls1.urls"), F.col("urls1.type")).show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|urls                                              |type                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|[url3, url4, url5, url6, url8, url9, url10, url11]|[link, link, link, link, link, link, link, link]|
+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, I was playing with your code a little and I wasn't able to solve one problem (probably lact of SQL knowledge) - If I have an empty list in the urls, how can I handle it? Giving me java.lang.NullPointerException. Understand that it's connected with reading from list and if the list is empty - it's gonna cause this error - most likely the expr(filter..)

Comment: @Leemosh if u have empty list in urls do want to leave that row as is?

Comment: I think I solved my problem with .filter(size('type_urls') > 0), but thanks anyway!